# Ending a user's turn after completing a quiz

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The title of this post is pretty self-explanatory.
Say I have a quiz system coded in PHP and a user is logged in to answer a question, how would we go about ending the user's turn after he/she answered the quiz correctly?

Consider this flowchart:

[image: Quiz question flowchart]

After the user answers the question correctly, I'd like to code a possible PHP function that will completely close that level so that the user won't have to answer it again, in addition to cheat by answering continuously and earning unnecessary points.

I was just wondering if there's a method or a work around this. Using a database to find out if the user has already answered the question was already in my list of ideas. But I was hoping someone would come up with something better.
I hope I made it clear.

Comment: simply record that the user has answered, and check against that record.

Comment: I assume that would mean using the database. That would work, however, I wouldn't want to have say 200 tables each in corresponding to a specific question in the system. So I'm searching for a better way or rather something more efficient.

Comment: no you would a have 1 question table , a user table and a user_answered table. Potentially more but not enough info; but certainly not one table per question!

Comment: Oh yea, sorry for the mistake. I meant 1 question table and about 200 columns or so. Please correct me if I'm wrong. This approach would work either ways. I'm just looking for another method if possible.
Thanks for the help

Comment: rows! not columns. another method than the most used and recomended - why?

Comment: Because I have occupied 50 rows of user details already. I wouldn't want to add more to it for the sake of simplicity in handling databases. Nonetheless though, I guess I'll be going for your method.
Thanks again for the help

Comment: Thought about sessions? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you track their answers throughout the quiz? I'd use sessions, storing each answer they give with the question ID. Don't award them any points until they click "Finish" and then store into a DB table:
what points they have been awarded from the session; current question ID; their user ID

Then when user goes to a question, check the database like (roughly):

```
SELECT
  TotalPoints
FROM
  tblQuestionsAnswered
WHERE
  UserID = $UserId AND
  QuestionID = $ThisQuestionId
```

If nothing returned they have not had any points from this question.

You do not want or need 200 tables. One table that per row stores:
questionID, userID, totalpoints, possibly something else

There is no better way if you want to be able to store records for a later date, ie when they log off, leave the site, come back later etc.
(please don't think about using a file, it'll be messy for this scenario)

You also need to consider other things, like if they have a session open for question A, if they go to question B are you going to destroy the other session and they have to start question A all over? I probs would or you'll have sessions all over the place, and why would anyone want to start one quiz, go to another and come back to that one later.

If you wanted them to be able to do this, you'd be best storing their progress in a DB table too. Perhaps you could use the table that stores their points (tblQuestionsAnswered in my above example) and have an additional column like "IsComplete".
If this is set to "yes" show them the points they already have for this completed question, if "no" then they start from a new and work through the question, if set to "partdone" then your script will query another table (eg tblQuestionProgress), drag their progress from that table into the session, remove their progress from that table, set the other table to IsComplete = no, and they're off.